# StopRoutingHandler issue and asp.net webform routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-routing

I came to know that `StopRoutingHandler` route. For example, this would stop routing on all js files. We could also set it up to ignore the entire script directory also, like below:

```cs
routes.Add(new Route("*\.jpg", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

I need to know where to put the line.
Do I need to put the line in `Application_Start`?

```cs
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("*\.jpg", new StopRoutingHandler()));
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source", "UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source/{ID}/{Title}", "~/UrlRewrite/Approach1/Source.aspx");
}
```

but before `MapPageRoute` or after `MapPageRoute`? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better get a lock before writing on the route table.

```cs
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
      using (RouteTable.Routes.GetWriteLock())
      {
        routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
      }
}
```